# How does one write intermediate Theano variables to file?

Tags: theano, deep-learning

During a Theano computation I would like to write a variable, say x, to a file. The subsequent computation requires data inside a file called 'scores.txt' which is why 'x' needs to be written to scores.txt. Is there any way we can write the value contained in x into scores.txt? Note that scores.txt will be used by a non-differentiable function (this function is not learnt and hence gradients with respect to operations of this function are not required) and hence any method which can just store the value of 'x' into 'scores.txt' during the theano computation is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

If x is a shared variable, just use `x.get_value()` to load the values from it as a python value, or a numpy array, then you can write it to file as you would normally do.

If x is a theano tensor variable, you can define a `theano.function` which takes the input of x (which should be available as a normal python or numpy data), and outputs x. You can then print and save the output of this function normally:

```
x_values = theano.function([x_input1, x_input2], x)
print x_values(x_input1, x_input2)
```